# Find the periocidity of a trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the period of the equation:

$f(x) = \sin(2x) - \sin(\frac{x}{2})$

My attempt:

$f'(x) = 2\cos(2x) - \frac{1}{2} \cos(\frac{x}{2})$

To find the period of the function I set it equal to zero to see when it crosses the x-axis.

$2\cos(2x) = \frac{1}{2} \cos(\frac{x}{2})$

But I can't get any further. How do I do it? Hints would be fantastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we know the period of $\sin x$ is $2\pi$, so the periods of $\sin\frac{x}{2}$ and $\sin2x$ are $4\pi$ and $\pi$ respectively, because the factor inside the $\sin$ function stretches the graph parallel to the $x$-axis.

To find the period of $f(x)=\sin2x+\sin\frac{x}{2}$ we simply find the lowest common multiple (LCM) of their periods. So the period of $f$ is $\mathrm{lcm}(\pi, 4\pi)=4\pi$.

**EDIT:**

Why can we just take the LCM?

Suppose $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ and $g$ and $h$ have periods $a$ and $b$ respectively. This means that $g(x)=g(x+a)$ and $h(x)=h(x+b)$ for all $x$.

Letting $c=\mathrm{lcm}(a, b)$ we see that $f(x+c)=g(x+c)+h(x+c)=g(x)+h(x)=f(x)$ since $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, so the period of $f$ divides $c$. Similarly we can see the LCM is the smallest number which satisfies this logic, and so must indeed be the period of $f$.

Comment: That makes some sense, but how do you see or know to take the lowest common multiple? I don't see why that would give the period of the functions combined @Siwel

Comment: See edit. Think of adding two functions in terms of a graph - if both functions repeat every $4\pi$ then the sum will of course also repeat with that period, because it behaves the same in the first $4\pi$ and the second $4\pi$ etc., and if a function repeats over $\pi$ it also repeats over $4\pi$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense :)